# Solr TrieFloat and SortableFloatField, which is best for float number sorting

Tags: sorting, solr, floating-point

I have a Solr schema in which a field is declared as TrieFloatField:

```
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

(...)

    <field
                name="someField"
                type="tfloat"
                indexed="true"
                stored="false"
                multiValued="false" />
```

If I use it to sort the results like so:

```
solrQuery.addSortField("someField", ORDER.asc);
solrQuery.addSortField("score", ORDER.desc);
```

The float numbers are not returned in correct numerical order, i.e.: I'd get results such as :

0.31 0.67 0.80 15.13 0.09 15.13 0.04

What's even stranger is that when I use this field to sort my results, some sorting DOES happen (they're in a different order that if, let's say, I don't use any sort field at all). Also, even if I change the sort order from asc to desc, the results are in the same order.

I thought that the TrieFloat type would work well for this. However I now see in the docs that they only mention that it's "Floating point field accessible Lucene TrieRange processing":

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieFloatField.html

and I honestly don't really know what that means. I also see that there's a SortableFloatField:

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/solr/solr-core/3.5.0/solr-core-3.5.0-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/solr/schema/SortableFloatField.html

but the docs don't really say anything about how it behaves when being used as a sort criteria.

My question simply is: which one of those two types (or what other type) is good for storing float numbers such that they can be used for proper (natural) ascending and descending sorting in a Solr query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both classes should work, but `TrieFloatField` will require much less memory than `SortableDoubleField` (given that the former uses a float field cache while the latter uses a String field cache). Note that if you don't need to perform range queries, you should set `precisionStep=0`.

However the bug you hit is very strange...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turns out that my sorting error was due to a mistake in my usage of Solr's Java API, and not related to the chosen filed type. How ever your answer helped in confirming that it was not the chosen filed type that was at issue here and set me on the right track to finding the issue. Now that I've fixed my Java code I'm using TrieFloatFiled and the sort happens as expected (float values are sorted in natural order).